# Jquery Sortable withset placeholder forever

Tags: jquery, clone, jquery-ui-sortable

I hope someone can help me.

My Problem:
I have 2 sortable UL's. 
`<ul id="k1"> and <ul id="k2">`

When i drag a li from k2 into k1, the k2 ul collapse (coz there is one li missing now).

Is it possible to say 
-> When draggable start, insert a non draggable clone into the k2?

and

If drag successful
-> Put LI into k1

if not
-> Put LI Back to the k2 and remove the clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what I wanted: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/sortable.html